# While scanf timer C

Tags: c

My program is supposed to prompt the user to answer a question, then allow only a limited time, such as 10 seconds, for the user to answer.

I have attempted to implement that with a `while` loop (see below).  On each iteration, the loop `sleep()`s for one second then tries to read an answer via `scanf()`. The number of iterations corresponds to the time allowed to answer, in seconds.

My program is not working correctly: if the user does not answer then the loop does not iterate.  How can I fix it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    int input;
    int i;

    while(i<10) {
        printf("some thing like (3+3*8+9) \n");
        printf("%d \n",i);

        sleep(1);

        scanf("%d",input);

        i++
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ISO C does not have a `sleep` function. You seem to be using a platform-specific extension. Please tag your question appropriately (e.g. `posix`, `linux`).

Comment: You would need to use a non-blocking function for input.

Comment: "My program is supposed to". Is this a homework? What is the name of the course?

Comment: The problem is that on most operating systems, input is, by default, line-based, which means that an input function will block the program until the user has finished entering the line. You can either use `select`, as specified in the duplicate question, or you can use a more flexible API such as [`ncurses`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses).

Comment: aka "asychrounous" function (e.g. "trap handler"); handled by OS, not really C directly, so commands vary. 
 The Timeout Function suggested by Oka worked for me "out of the box" :-).  I'm on a Mac, 10.13.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be difficult (and probably impossible) to do what you wish using C standard library functions, such as `scanf()`.

You should consult an Application Programming Interface (API) that provides non-blocking input function, such as POSIX's `select()` function, which you can read about it [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html). This manual page includes an example code which you can reference.

(I am suggesting POSIX, because you already seem to be using a POSIX API by using the `sleep()` function).